# APC - Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, apc

Here is what I have in my PHP.ini:

```
extension=php_apc.dll
...    
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
```

I'm running Apache 2.0.59, PHP version 5.2.3 on Windows Server 2003.

I've already installed XDebug compiled with vc6. Thus, I got the APC version 5.2 vc6. Here are both filenames that I downloaded (and put the *.dll in php/ext/).

php_apc-3.1.5-5.2-vc6-x86.zip
php_apc-3.1.5-5.2-nts-vc6-x86.zip

I got them [here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/).

I've tried rebooting the server and in both cases, I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/php_apc.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, I went [here](https://www.php.net/releases/index.php)
2. Then, I downloaded [Collection of PECL modules for PHP 5.2.3](http://museum.php.net/php5/pecl-5.2.3-Win32.zip)
3. Then, I extracted the php_apc.dll file and copied it in the ext/ folder
4. Restarted Apache
5. It works!

Answer (score 5):

Try using the full drive letter and path to `extension_dir` in `php.ini`:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\somedir\php\ext"
```

And restart Apache after making the change.

(It might very well be something else, but this is the first thing I check on Windows systems -- those pesky filepaths.)

Comment: It didn't help, I got this: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\php\\ext\\php_apc.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus If php_apc.dll is really in C:\php\ext\ AND extension=php_apc.dll is uncommented as you show above, AND if you have *other* libraries in C:\php\ext\ and those libraries are also properly accounted for in php.ini and Apache & PHP startup just fine with those libraries enabled but not php_apc.dll, then that points to a problem with the library.  Does everything else work?

Comment: Yes, everything else checks out... recently installed Xdebug (vc6) without any issues (currently doing tracing with it too).

Comment: Ok, well then I'm at a loss except to say that if you search for php_apc.dll here at StackOverflow, you will see a lot of questions, and the answers point to several idiosyncrasies between versions of APC, PHP, etc and the need to be very specific.  Sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: I downloaded a PECL archive for php 5.2.3 and the apc DLL included in there seems to work (no, error message thus far).

Comment: Excellent! Glad it was "just" a bad library.

Comment: I did everything on this page but it sills generates `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/php5/ext\\php_pdo_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 1):

To complete other answers:

Using the **non thread safe (NTS)** version of the DLL instead of the thread safe one solved the problem for me.

That is, only the NTS version was compatible with my WAMP installation.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this:

> Note: On Windows, APC needs a temp path to exist, and be writable by the web server. It checks the TMP, TEMP and USERPROFILE environment variables in that order and finally tries the WINDOWS directory if none of those are set.

http://php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the DLL has the correct *architecture* level. I had the same problem trying to load the file from php_apc-3.1.10-5.**4**-vc6-x86.zip. It didn't work, while the DLL from php_apc-3.1.10-5.**3**-vc6-x86.zip worked. I don't know how to find the right file without fiddling in the PHP repository though. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had listed apcu before apc.

```
extension=apc
extension=apcu
```

Reordering them so apcu was first, solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using **macOS Catalina** and was trying to install extension **APCU** for **PHP 5.6**.

So i ran below commands:

1. `brew install autoconf`
2. `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`
3. `pecl install apcu-4.0.11`

At this stage my php5.6 ini got input **extension="apcu.so"**
But i was getting warning saying the apcu.so wasn't found under
**/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20131226/** directory.

The installer put the **apcu.so** at **/usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40/pecl/20131226/apcu.so**

so i copied the apcu.so to the desired directory

```
cp /usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40/pecl/20131226/apcu.so /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20131226/
```

and i'm done.